# giving effect while changing a image with javascript and css3

Tags: javascript, css, css-transitions, transition

i want to change a image with javascript using the code:

```
    document.getElementById("").setAttribute("src","");
```

and giving it a effect using css3

```
    #id{transition:1s;}
```

but it doesn't work
how can i do it correctly using CSS3 and javascript

Comment: The CSS `transition` property is meant for well - CSS transitions. Here you are changing an HTML attribute that is completely unrelated to any CSS property.

Answer (score 0):

Not all properties are transition-able. [Here's](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Using_CSS_transitions) a list of those that can be controlled.

If you want to fade between them, it may take a more hacky solution involving a new element overlaid on top of the original, combined with `opacity:0` and `transition:1s`.

Comment: `src` is *not* a property. It is an HTML *attribute* and completely out of the realm of CSS (except for maybe in selectors).